# How to get <th> to loop through fetch results without being in a table loop

Tags: php, html, while-loop, html-table

I am designing a table and I am having difficulties with a `<th>`. The `<th>` is usernames from my database, so I need to fetch them, so that they can even display on the page. I am currently fetching everything from my database table through a fetch while loop. Whenever, I put the `<th>` in my loop it ruins the structure of my table.

I am trying to create a table that looks like this...

Rnd  username1   username2   username3

1    player 1     player1     player1

2    player2      player2     player2

3    player3      player3     player3

However, the table looks like this...

[image]

My code looks like this

```
<table class="draft_border_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Rnd</th>

        </tr>
<?php
$count = 1;
while($draft_order_row = mysqli_fetch_array($draft_order_stmt)) {
    $count + 1;
    $username = $draft_order_row['username'];
    $player1 = $draft_order_row['player1'];
    $player2 = $draft_order_row['player2'];
    $player3 = $draft_order_row['player3'];
    $player4 = $draft_order_row['player4'];
    $player5 = $draft_order_row['player5'];
    $player6 = $draft_order_row['player6'];
    $player7 = $draft_order_row['player7'];
    $player8 = $draft_order_row['player8'];
    $player9 = $draft_order_row['player9'];
    $player10 = $draft_order_row['player10'];
    $player11 = $draft_order_row['player11'];
    $player12 = $draft_order_row['player12'];
    $player13 = $draft_order_row['player13'];
    $player14 = $draft_order_row['player14'];
?>
        <th><?php echo "<div>" . $username . "</div>"; ?></th>      
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player1 . "</div>"; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player2 . "</div>"; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player3 . "</div>"; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo "<div class='draftBorder'>" . $player4 . "</div>"; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
//etc table rows for players
}
?>
    </table>
```

How can I still have my usernames as my loop through the fetched results and be out of the loop for the table?

UPDATE

New pic based on an answer.

[image]

```
user_players
CREATE TABLE `user_players` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `firstname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player1` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player2` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player3` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player4` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player5` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player6` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player7` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player8` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player9` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player10` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player11` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player12` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player13` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player14` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=284 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `<th>`s in `<tr>`s. `<th>` denotes a cell in the header. Not the whole header.

You should produce HTML that looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <th>username1</th>
  <th>username2</th>
  <th>username3</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Adding the `<tr>` to my username `<th>` Did not help. I want all of those rows under each username. I want the usernames to appear inline.

Comment: I have it in a loop. This isn't static data.

Comment: So what? Produce this HTML in the loop. It's about structure, you see?